# why my object get from last to first in for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i confuse about array

my data is

[image]

and my for loop

```
 for (var data in statInfo["segment"][0]) {
       console.log(data)
 }
```

and my result is

data print is

segment5
segment4
segment3
segment2
segment1

thank you

Comment: Object properties do not have an order. If you need it in order, use an array.

Comment: You're looping over an object and not an array.

Comment: And if it was an array (which is not), [using “for…in” with array iteration is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea#500531).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 2):

Enumeration of object properties is not alphabetical.

In fact it is [left to implementations to decide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties).

Most browsers implement according to order of property creation IIRC.

If you need ordering use an `Array`, `Map` or `Set`.

Finally, in ES2015, you can make an object iterable by defining your own iteration function, which can have any order or enumeration you need.

```js
var obj = { 
    foo: '1', 
    bar: '2',
    bam: '3',
    bat: '4',
};

obj[Symbol.iterator] = iter.bind(null, obj);

function* iter(o) {
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
        yield o[keys[i]];
    }
}

for(var v of obj) { console.log(v); } // '1', '2', '3', '4'
```

Comment: Note: the code in my answer will only work in very modern browsers.

Comment: i think that 'yield' make function error . it see yield to variable in javascript